# Modulo 2*Pi using SSE/SSE2

Tags: c, optimization, floating-point, simd, sse

I'm still pretty new to using SSE and am trying to implement a modulo of `2*Pi` for double-precision inputs of the order `1e8` (the result of which will be fed into some vectorised trig calculations).

My current attempt at the code is based around the idea that `mod(x, 2*Pi) = x - floor(x/(2*Pi))*2*Pi` and looks like:

```
#define _PD_CONST(Name, Val)                                            \
static const double _pd_##Name[2] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = { Val, Val }  

_PD_CONST(2Pi, 6.283185307179586);  /* = 2*pi  */  
_PD_CONST(recip_2Pi, 0.159154943091895); /* = 1/(2*pi)  */

void vec_mod_2pi(const double * vec, int Size, double * modAns)
{
    __m128d sse_a, sse_b, sse_c;
    int i;
    int k = 0;
    double t = 0;

    unsigned int initial_mode;
    initial_mode = _MM_GET_ROUNDING_MODE();

    _MM_SET_ROUNDING_MODE(_MM_ROUND_DOWN);

    for (i = 0; i < Size; i += 2)
    {
        sse_a = _mm_loadu_pd(vec+i);
        sse_b = _mm_mul_pd( _mm_cvtepi32_pd( _mm_cvtpd_epi32( _mm_mul_pd(sse_a, *(__m128d*)_pd_recip_2Pi) ) ), *(__m128d*)_pd_2Pi);
        sse_c = _mm_sub_pd(sse_a, sse_b);
        _mm_storeu_pd(modAns+i,sse_c);
    }

    k = i-2;
    for (i = 0; i < Size%2; i++)
    {
        t = (double)((int)(vec[k+i] * 0.159154943091895)) * 6.283185307179586;
        modAns[k+i] = vec[k+i] - t;
    }

    _MM_SET_ROUNDING_MODE(initial_mode);
}
```

Unfortunately, this is currently returning a lot of `NaN` with a couple of answers of `1.128e119` as well (some what outside the range of `0` -> `2*Pi` that I was aiming for!). I suspect that where I'm going wrong is in the double-to-int-to-double conversion that I'm trying to use to do the `floor`.

Can anyone suggest where I've gone wrong and how to improve it?

P.S. sorry about the format of that code, it's the first time I've posted a question on here and can't seem to get it to give me empty lines within the code block to make it readable.

Comment: Perhaps I should make it a wee bit clearer - I'm not super-concerned by accuracy of result here (in fact if it returned with single-precision accuracy, that would be fine). What I'm most concerned with is a) getting it to run in SSE so I can get rid of an unnecessary store/load that I've got at the moment between two other SSE blocks and b) making it run quickly if possible.

Comment: First of all, use `_mm_set1_pd(6.283185307179586)` like a normal person; the compiler is already smart enough to turn that into the equivalent of `static const double[2]`, but with duplicate elimination (like for duplicate string literals).  Second, you can use `_mm_cvttpd_epi32` (note the extra t for truncate) to convert to integer with truncation instead of the current rounding mode.  If your numbers are positive, that's the same as `floor`.  If you have SSE4.1, you can use `_mm_floor_pd` (`roundpd`) to round to integer directly instead of converting to signed int32_t and back.

Comment: It's not clear why you'd get NaN, though. Cvt outside the `-2^31..2^31-1` range will give you `0x80000000` (i.e. -2^31, the most negative integer), which Intel uses as the "integer indefinite value". Converting that back to `double` should succeed.  Those might be your `1.128e119` results?  It's expected that you get catastrophic cancellation errors, especially since your `2Pi * recip_2Pi` probably isn't exactly 1.0 because the rounding errors will be different. (Actually `1.0- 2Pi*recip_2Pi` with `gcc -O0` is only ~2.1E-15, so that's several orders of magnitude smaller than your inputs.)

Answer (score 7):

If you want any kind of accuracy, the simple algorithm is terribly bad. For an accurate range reduction algorithm, see e.g. [Ng et al., ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS: Good to the Last Bit](http://www.derekroconnor.net/Software/Ng--ArgReduction.pdf) (now available via the Wayback Machine: [2012-12-24](https://web.archive.org/web/20121224072516/http://www.derekroconnor.net/Software/Ng--ArgReduction.pdf))

Comment: I need to go through that paper again to make sure that I've understood it but does that method not require more bits than are available in XMM registers? Is that method actually workable in SSE?

Comment: @BigA: Indeed, you can't fit all of the bits into a single XMM reg at a time. You'll have to do something more sophisticated.

Comment: An advantage of a simple "fmod 2pi" algorithm which should not be overlooked is that rounding errors introduced thereby will often counteract earlier rounding errors in the computation of the angle.  For example, the result of the expression `Math.Sin(x*(2*Math.Pi))` will generally be more accurate if `Sin` performs argument reduction mod `Math.Pi` than if it performs reduction mod π [for some values of x, the reduction mod π will work out slightly better, but for some it works out much worse].

Answer (score 1):

For large arguments [Hayne-Panek algorithm](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1057600.1057602) is typically used. However, the Hayne-Panek paper is quite difficult to read, and I suggest to have a look at [Chapter 11 in the Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://web.archive.org/web/20121006232002/http://www.springerlink.com:80/content/h886863382gg4u83/) for a more accessible explanation.